# ServiceWorker - update cached response (due to POSTing a change to backend)

Tags: javascript, http, caching, service-worker

In our ServiceWorker app, we cache responses including for resources that are searched for:

```
https://webservices.geodesy.gov.au/siteLogs/search/findByFourCharacterId?id=ADE1&format=geodesyml
```

When we save a modified resource with a POST, a subsequent search returns the old cached page.  Until a refresh is done to repopulate the cache.

Is there a best way to return the new resource?

I was planning on updating the cached resource with the new version.  Though I can't easily see how you can re-craft the response.

---

We just though about deleting the entry from the cache so then it will have to go back to the network (in our model of how we use SW).

---

**New information I forgot to include before:** this is a cache first service worker (https://jakearchibald.com/2014/offline-cookbook/#cache-falling-back-to-network).